# Connection between Jupyter Notebook and Gsheet - Failed - HttpError 403 Error

Tags: api, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook

I`m completetly new using Google Cloud Platform and APIs so I don`t know how to fix this issue.
I`m trying to connect my Jupyter notebook with a google sheet so I can connect a dataset on Jupyter to Gsheet.

I made all the connections and didn`t get any error, for my last step I used the code below:

```
from df2gspread import df2gspread as d2g
wks_name = 'Jupyter Manipulated Data'
    d2g.upload(df_apn1, wks_name, credentials=credentials, row_names=True)
```

and received this error :

```
HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/root?fields=id&alt=json returned "Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.">
```

I haven`t found any solution here that could fix this and, as I said before, I don`t have experience with this so I really have no idea how to fix it.
I made sure that everything that was suppose to be enable is so this is not the issue.

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Thank you

Comment: You might have not assigned the correct [scope](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/service-accounts#accesscopesiam) or [permission](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/service-accounts#usingroles) to the service account you are using. Do you get the same error after following [this guide](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-integrate-google-sheets-and-jupyter-notebooks-c469309aacea) thoroughly?

Comment: it worked, you were right, I was not using the correct scope. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the credentials created have the right scope. The specific information about scopes when using Google Sheets can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes#sheets).

This [medium article](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-integrate-google-sheets-and-jupyter-notebooks-c469309aacea) serves as a very nice tutorial.